# NSUserDefaults changed IOS app crashing after update

Tags: ios, xcode6.4

updated  IOS app with changes in  NSUser default keys ( added few more keys and changed some existing  key names) app is crashing at initialization time after updating from store . If I delete the app completely and reinstall it then it is working fine . We can not clear previous NSUser defaults and recreate it when updating app  ( I mean complete re-installation by writing some logic in updated app)?.

Comment: this question might be more easily answered if you showed what the crash was (you can use the Xcode console to do that)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear `NSUserDefault` with below code.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"yourkey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to synchronize the user defaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"YourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];yourkey
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to write a migrator routine which checks for certain former keys when the application launches and updates the defaults database respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you can usuually clean out the entire NSUserDefaults by doing this, just in case you forgot the key or something:

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary]  forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if app is opening for first time then clear `NSUserDefault` as below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary]  forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

After that set your `NSUserDefault` again as per your requirement.